# Creating a user-based recommendation engine?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data set of some **questions** and **answers** that users have completed by choices. I'm trying to build a recommendation engine to find similar users based on their answers on top of this.

So for each user I have a data like this:

```
user_1, {"question_id": "choice_id", ...}
user_2, {"question_id": "choice_id", ...}
```

I've found clustering and similarity algorithms will be helpful and I've chosen Apache Spark's **RowMatrix** **columnSimilarities** to be very efficient.

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import RowMatrix

rows = sc.parallelize([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])

mat = RowMatrix(rows)

mat.columnSimilarities(threshold)
```

My question is how should I transform my data to get an input like this?
I've found **scikit-learn's DictVectorizer** may be helpful but the problem is users complete questions randomly so I can't use questions as features.